# React not loading background image

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am trying to get a full screen background image to load on a landing page but I cannot seem to get the image to load when I reference it in the CSS

I can reference it from within my React Component using `<img src={require('../assets/img/header.jpg')} />` and it loads correctly but if I load it in the CSS file it doesn't work

My css file is as follows

```css
body, html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.bg {
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url("../img/header.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

}
```

and my react component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../assets/css/landing.css'

class Landing extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="bg">
                <div className="center">
                    <a href="index.html" className="button is-info is-rounded is-centered is-medium">Get Started</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

All that is displayed is the get started button, not the image

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using `create-react-app` or a boilerplate for React that pulls in the `image-loader`. Whenever you do a require, it loads the image as a data image or (if the file is extremely large) as file with a filepath different from what you set (because React will then bundle and know where exactly to put and reference the image).

Referring to it in CSS may not be the ideal solution because of the reasons mentioned above.

You can always try this approach (setting the background image):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// This is more of a recommendation, you can still use the require if you want to
import Image from '../../image';   

export default function() {
    return (
        <div className="to-change-background-of" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Image})`}} />
    );
}
```

That should pull the image using the reasons I specified above, this time setting the background image.

One thing (I'm not sure why) about this is that the `background` (when you are using CSS) property tends to break in some browsers. So in the cSS

```
.to-change-background {
    background: #EEE no-repeat center;
}
```

This may break the code. You may have to break it down (ignoring linting)

```
.to-change-background {
    background-color: #EEE;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, if I open up the dev tools and open the image url in the sources I can still see the image loaded both with your version and loading it in the CSS, which makes me think its a CSS error

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve, please?